# Will there be a surjective homomorphism...?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there a surjective (onto) homomorphism from $\Bbb Q$ to the group $\Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z$? Is there a subgroup of $\Bbb Q$ of index $2$? Why or why not?

*I just want to check if I'm doing this right. 
I got yes for the first part, and no for the second. Is that correct?*

Comment: An answer of yes for the first part implies yes for the second.  Did you have a homomorphism in mind?

Comment: Oops! I was definitely approaching this incorrectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: the two parts are equivalent. If such a homomorphism exists, then its kernel is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ of index $2$. But the homomorphism does not exist. For choose some element $ x\in \mathbb{Q}$ that gets mapped to $1$. What does $\frac{x}{2}$ get mapped to?

Answer (score 0):

An epimorphism $A \to B$ of abelian groups induces an epimorphism $A/2A \to B/2B$. We have $\mathbb{Q}/2\mathbb{Q}=0$ and $C_2 / (2 C_2) = C_2$, hence there is no epimorphism $\mathbb{Q} \to C_2$.